# a problemm in data display with android and JSON

Tags: android, json

I have a problem in displaying data with android and JSON
I have a problem in displaying data with android and JSON
I have a problem in displaying data with android and JSON
I have a problem in displaying data with android and JSON

```
public JSONParser() {
}
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    try {
        if (method == "POST") {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));


HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        } else if (method == "GET") {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);


HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    return jObj;
}
```

}

**line 72 :**

```
success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
```

**error**

[image]

Comment: where is the line `votre_compte.java:72` ??

Comment: @A.S. line 72 : success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

Comment: Please put more code. The above code is insufficient.

Comment: Yeah koherent is right, also make a check before returning the jsonObj if the Integer is available. also post your json

Comment: do not appen `\n` on a json string!  it should be `sb.append(line);`

Comment: There are only two ways `success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);` could throw a `NullPointerException`. Either `json` is `null` or `TAG_SUCCESS` is `null`.

Comment: I can not put all the codes

Answer (score 0):

json should be null in your code. Check whether the json object is created before using it. 
You can solve this exception by

```
if(json != null)
     success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
```

But this will not solve the complete problem. You need to find out why this object is not created.

Answer (score 0):

The json object is null, so you get null pointer exception. I can't say why because you have not pasted the full code.

It's beyond your question, but using the built in libraries for web services communication and JSON parsing is waste of time. For me optimal is retrofit + gson (they work great together) and integration into the project take few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Your json object is wrongly populated.Try this:

```
String jsonData = sb.toString();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
success = json.getInt(Tag_SUCCESS);
```